# What does this Intel assembly code mean?

Tags: assembly, intel, microprocessors, 8085

The following is a program to find the greater of 2 numbers:

[image]

In the above program what does **EQU** denote? And what does the instruction **MVI A,01H** do in EQU?

What does **PORT1** denote here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EQU` and `GRT` are labels.  The lines

```
CMP C
JZ  EQU
```

compare the value in the `C` register with the value in the `A` register and jump to the label `EQU` if they're equal.  (The processor subtracts the two values; `JZ` means "Jump if Zero," that is, if the difference is 0.)

The `MVI` command probably means "Move Immediate," so the line

```
MVI A,01H
```

moves the value 01H (1 in hexadecimal, which is just 1) into `A`.

The line

```
OUT PORT1
```

probably means to OUTput the value of `A` to the pins on Port 1 on the processor.